# Python find location of string is a binary file, Count specific offsets before it, and save that data from that offset to EOF

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a binary file. What I want to achieve is find a particular string in that file (example I want to find where document string is)

I am using python 2.7

This is my code.

```
file = sys.argv[1]
f = open(file,mode='rb')
print(f.index("apple"))
buff = f.read()
f.close()
```

What I am getting is "AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'index'"

And after finding the offset of this string, I want to count backwards 10 bytes and then write data from that offset to EOF (end of file).

Comment: `buff.index(b"apple")`

Comment: Thanks, it solved almost all of my question :) I can proceed further from here.